# How to use CSS3 parser with HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: css, selenium, jquery-selectors, webdriver, htmlunit

For example.
I have a selector for the active menu item:

```js
$("ul#menu li a[href='/']")
```

And selector for the rest menu items (1):

```js
$("ul#menu li a:not([href='/'])")
```

But ":not" was appeared in CSS3 and didn't supported by HtmlUnitDriver. I've tried with

> org.seleniumhq.selenium : selenium-htmlunit-driver : 2.28.0

Also I've tried next selector (2)

```js
$("ul#menu li a[href!='/']")
```

Both (1) and (2) works fine in the real browsers like Firefox or Google Chrome through jQuery.
(1) works with FirefoxDriver and (2) don't.

Which version of HtmlUnitDriver should I use to enable CSS3 support? And where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that HtmlUnit developers tried to add CSS3 support but failed and reverted it for some reasons.
http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/7898

So, we wouldn't see correct HtmlUnitDriver until they are done their job.

Comment: Anyway, is it possible for you to use XPath expressions in the meantime? It should work well given that you you Selenium...

Comment: Yes, I can use XPaths and they are works.
Here the same functionality example `//ul[@id="menu"]/li/a[@href!="/"]`. But I'm also using Geb which doesn't support XPath inside Pages.
Though I found partial ugly but reusable from Specs solution for CSS. But I think this Geb specific stuff is offtopic here in context of WebDriver.

Thanks for your advice in any case.

Answer (score 0):

i've got one idea. try using js code and insert it in jsExecutor in this way:
[image]

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = ($("ul a:not([href='/'])")[23]);");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this works for u.

Comment: Thanks for the assumption, but it doesn't work.
Nor "$" nor "jQuery" visible for the scipt engine at all.

Here is exact error message:
`net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (injected script#1)`

Comment: well. open your website and open simple console in firebug (firefox). try to type there something like that: ($("ul a:not([href='/'])")[23]).click()  and you\ll get to know whether jQuery is supported or jQuery is not supported

Comment: in case if jQuery is not supported the way to make everything work is getElementsByTagName('a')[n-th order].click()

Comment: As I wrote in the original question, all JS works fine in the real browsers and even with the FirefoxDriver. Now I want to see the same with the HtmlUnitDriver. getElementsByTagName doesn't feet to my requirements as it doesn't support CSS-selectors and overcomplicates my code.